# Integration Testing Spring Boot service using Eureka services

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, service-discovery, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to figure out how to build integration tests on a Spring Boot application that uses Eureka.  Say I have a test

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
public class MyIntegrationTest {
  @Autowired
  protected WebApplicationContext webAppContext;

  protected MockMvc mockMvc;
  @Autowired
  RestTemplate restTemplate;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  @Test
  public void testServicesEdgeCases() throws Exception {

    // test no registered services
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/services").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$").value(jsonArrayWithSize(0)));

    }
}
```

and I have in my code path for that api call:

```
DiscoveryManager.getInstance().getDiscoveryClient().getApplications();
```

This will NPE.  The discoveryClient is returned as null.  Code works fine if I start the Spring boot app directly and use the API myself.   I have no specific profile usage anywhere.  Is there something special wrt Eureka that I need to configure for the discovery client to get constructed for testing?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't/don't want to run your test with `@IntegrationTest` like [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/eureka/blob/master/src/test/java/eurekademo/ApplicationTests.java)?

Comment: Yup.. you are right.  I could use `@IntegrationTest` or `@WebIntegrationTest`.  Cant keep up with all these new annotations!  Solves the problem perfectly.  I will answer and modify the code for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @Donovan who answered in the comments.  There are annotations built by Phillip Web and Dave Syer in the `org.springframework.boot.test` package that I was unaware of.  Wanted to provide an answer with the changed code.  Change the class annotations to:

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
@IntegrationTest
```

or if you are using spring boot 1.2.1 and greater

```
@WebIntegrationTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
```

Comment: This solves the startup, but how do you provide the URLs of the surrounding system in this faked eureka client?